# under hange root environment: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java

Actually I have solved the problem but I don't understand why it works.

I have been developing under a change root environment, which was configured by someone else. I tried to use java command, but got that error message in the title.

After searching for solutions to this problem, I found no one works for my situation. Then I downloaded the newest java package from Oracle website and put it somewhere in my change root environment. By running ./java in .../jre.../bin, I tried test whether this new one works and it did work.

Then the thing I cannot understand happened. After testing the new jre, the old java command is fixed and I don't get the error message any more. I have used "java -version" to check the version of the java command and it was the old version.

Can someone explain?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16656/problem-to-launch-java-at-debian-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjli  might help

Comment: @Dawnkeeper I have read this article but it's different situation. I am already root user after changing root.